Visual VM is not showing Profiler tab for Containerized Application
I am running a Micronaut Dockerized Application based on adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine and trying to profile it using VisaulVm 2.1 but it's not showing Profile and Sampler Tab.

I can see VisualVm JDK home and my App JVM is pointing to OpenJdk 11 ,64bit.


I have gone through other SO posts and can see the answers mentioned about difference of 32 and 64 bit version but here in my case it's same.
Any suggestion to fix this ?
